# "Requests specifying Server Side Encryption with AWS KMS managed keys require AWS Signature Version 4" when copying data from HDFS to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hdfs, distcp

I am trying to use **distcp** to copy data from HDFS to S3, but I got an error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.S3Exception: org.jets3t.service.S3ServiceException: S3 Error Message. -- ResponseCode: 400, ResponseStatus: Bad Request, XML Error Message: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Error><Code>InvalidArgument</Code><Message>Requests specifying Server Side Encryption with AWS KMS managed keys require AWS Signature Version 4.</Message>
```

Here is my command:

```
hadoop distcp \
-Dfs.s3.awsAccessKeyId="<access_key>" \
-Dfs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey="<secret_access_key>" \
-Dmapred.task.timeout=10000000 \
-strategy dynamic \
-update \
<hdfs_dir> \
<s3_dir>
```

Do I need to specify any config in the distcp command or there is any config change on S3 bucket? Thanks

Comment: did you made it work ?